# Controlling background jobs in PowerShell 4 scripts

Tags: powershell, sas, background-process

I have a series of SAS programs that I run in the background using a PowerShell script kicked off from Task Scheduler.

I would like for each program to finish first before starting the other.

I've tried many different approaches using the examples I've found on this site but none seem to work. What I'm specifically not able to find is the state of a job running in the background and then use that state in a conditional statement to check that the first program running in the background is completed before starting the second program.

For instance, if I use:

```
$job01 = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { & "C:\Program Files\SASHome\SASFoundation\9.4\sas.exe" -sysin "D:\EDM\SASPROGRAMS\ABC.sas" -nosplash -log D:\EDM\SASLOGS -work D:\SASWork }
```

then

```
Get-Job
```

I'll see that `$job01` is Completed right after issuing `Get-Job`, when the SAS program itself takes about 10 min to complete.

What cmdlet can I use to determine when the SAS program running in the background has completed?

Comment: Thanks for editing, Alex.

Answer (score 5):

The call operator `&` fires and forgets. Try `Start-Process` with the `-Wait` switch. Try:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\SASHome\SASFoundation\9.4\sas.exe" -ArgumentList "-sysin `"D:\EDM\SASPROGRAMS\ABC.sas`" -nosplash -log D:\EDM\SASLOGS -work D:\SASWork" -NoNewWindow
```

Remember to escape doublequotes (using a backtick) inside the arguments-string.

Comment: I would remove the job wrapper, though. Since the OP wants to start the next job only after the current one completed there's not much point in using jobs in the first place.

Comment: Good point. Read it too fast. Thought he meant multiple processes inside the job's scriptblock. :-)

Comment: Frode, thanks very much for your response.

Ansgar, what do you mean by "remove the job wrapper"? Not clear on how to do that.

Comment: I already did it in the answer (removed `Start-Job -ScriptBlock {  #keep this }` part)